# Who rebutted Raul Hilberg's allegation that Man's Search for Meaning was a deception?

Tags: german-language, viktor-frankl, mans-search-for-meaning

[*Man's Search for Meaning*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man%27s_Search_for_Meaning) by psychiatrist Viktor Frankl is a well-known book in which the author described his experiences in several concentration camps (including Auschwitz) and discussed the question of the meaning of life.

The Wikipedia article about the book has a section on [the book's reception](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Man%27s_Search_for_Meaning&oldid=1122481084#Reception), which contains the following paragraph (emphasis mine):

> In his book *Faith in Freedom*, psychiatrist [Thomas Szasz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Szasz) states that Frankl's survivor testimony was written to misdirect, and betrays instead an intent of a transparent effort to conceal Frankl's actions and his collaboration with the Nazis, and that, in the assessment of [Raul Hilberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raul_Hilberg), the founder of [Holocaust Studies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holocaust_studies), **Frankl's historical account is a deception** akin to [Binjamin Wilkomirski's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragments:_Memories_of_a_Wartime_Childhood) infamous memoirs, which were translated into nine languages before being exposed as fraudulent in Hilberg's 1996, *Politics of Memory*.<sup>[13]</sup> Szasz's criticism of Frankl is not universally embraced. Similarly, **Hilberg's allegations have been rebutted by several reviewers.<sup>[citation needed]</sup>**

I was familiar with both Viktor Frankl and Raul Hilberg before reading this, but not with what Hilberg had written about *Man's Search for Meaning*. Who rebutted Hilberg's allegations and how?

(The book was originally published in [German](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E2%80%A6_trotzdem_Ja_zum_Leben_sagen) in 1946, but it was the English translation that became a bestseller. The German Wikipedia article about the book doesn't say anything about deception or Hilberg.)

Comment: **Will to Meaning** I have both read and taught from Victor Frankl's books: *Man's Search for Meaning* and *Logotherapy*. The presentation of "The will to Meaning," as in contrast to "The will to Power" or "The Will to Pleasure," was a refreshing approach to psychology. His work became *The Third Viennese School of Psychology*. (After Freud and Adler) If this was all a fraud, it must be considered a brilliant hoax of biblical proportions! I have yet to read of these accusations, though they may indeed exist. The events of the Holocaust that people had to suffer were so horrible any one should