# When was the first time a Holocaust memoir or diary was exposed as a fraud?

Tags: history-of-literature

In my previous question, I asked [Who rebutted Raul Hilberg's allegation that Man's Search for Meaning was a deception?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/23729/2191) Viktor Frankl's book is not generally regarded as a deception or a fraud. Several memoirs of the Holocaust, however, have been exposed as a fraud and Wikipedia even has a category of articles about [Holocaust-related hoaxes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Holocaust-related_hoaxes). Looking at the examples and related articles, most of them seem relatively recent:

- *Au nom de tous les miens* (1971) by [Martin Gray](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martin_Gray_(writer)), translated as *For Those I Loved*, was described as a forgery by Holocaust historian Gitta Sereny in 1979. It may be an "embellished" account rather than a purely fraudulent one.
- [*Memorias del infierno*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enric_Marco) ("Memories or Memoir of Hell") by Enric Marco, published in 1978: this work was not exposed as a fraud by anybody else, but in 2005 the author admitted that his claims were false.
- [*Fragments: Memories of a Wartime Childhood*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragments:_Memories_of_a_Wartime_Childhood), (1995), published under the pseudonym Binjamin Wilkomirski and debunked in 1998.
- [*Misha: A Mémoire of the Holocaust Years*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Misha:_A_M%C3%A9moire_of_the_Holocaust_Years) (1997) by Misha Defonseca was exposed as fraudulent in 2008.
- [*Hannah: From Dachau to the Olympics and Beyond*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hannah:_From_Dachau_to_the_Olympics_and_Beyond) (2005) by Jean Goodwin Messinger about [Hannah Pence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosemarie_Pence), who admitted in 2009 that her stories were fabrications.
- [*Angel at the Fence: The True Story of a Love That Survived*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angel_at_the_Fence), by Herman Rosenblat, originally scheduled for publication in 2009.

This is a rather disturbing "genre" of literature. Wikipedia's category of Holocaust-related hoaxes does not claim to be exhaustive, hence my question: when was the first time a Holocaust memoir or diary was exposed as a fraud. For the purpose of this question, I am interested in purely fraudulent accounts rather than (for lack of a better term) "embellished" ones.